# Converting a double into date time

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a user input values in my table.
Here if user enters 3.2, it mean 3 hours and 20 min.

I am showing the total hours that has been input by the user in the entire week.

Inputs are:
Sun : 3.2
Mon : 4.5
Tue: 5.0

Now, 3.2 + 4.5 + 5.0 = 12.70 which would mean 12 hours and 70 min. 
However, I want the result to be 13.10 (which is 13 hours and 10 min) instead of 12.70.

I need the total in a select query which is binding my grid with the rest of the data.

Currently i am using the sum function in the select query along with other columns.

How do I do this?

Comment: Convert each numer to a datetime or timespan first and then apply Sum.

Comment: 13.70 hours can't be 13 hours and 70 minutes. 13.70 hours mean 13 hours 42 minutes.

Comment: "now 3.2+4.5+5.0 = 13.70 which would mean 13 hours and 70 min "` that should be 12 hours and 70 minutes ? isn't it ?

Comment: @Habib that was a mistake from my side.

Comment: Are you forced to use this method of time entry? If not I wouldn't go this route, unless you are validating the user input, and then immediately converting that into a proper date/time format.

Comment: Use `TimeSpan` instead of `double`, as others said. Still, if you insist on using `double`, here are two methods for you: `static double ConvertFromSexagesimal(double hoursPointMinutes) { double wholePart = Math.Truncate(hoursPointMinutes); return wholePart + (hoursPointMinutes - wholePart) / 0.60; } static double ConvertToSexagesimal(double hoursPointDecimalFractionalHours) { double wholePart = Math.Truncate(hoursPointDecimalFractionalHours); double retVal = wholePart + (hoursPointDecimalFractionalHours - wholePart) * 0.60; return Math.Round(retVal, 2); }`. I leave the rest to you guys.

Answer (score 3):

Your input format won't work at all.

You are lucky it does in your example but in most cases it just won't. For instance, if 2 persons input "1 hour and 50 minutes" :

1.5 + 1.5 = 3.0

You cannot read it as : "three hours" since in reality it is "3 hours and 40 minutes".

As soon as the sum of "minutes" is greater thant 0.99, your are wrong.

---

But in the few lucky cases, you can do some arithmetic (if you want a result in the same "double" format as your input)?

```
var inputList = new List<double>() {3.2, 4.5, 5.0};
double total = inputList.Sum();

int baseHours = (int)Math.Floor(total);
int realBaseHours = (int)inputList.Sum(d => Math.Floor(d));

if (baseHours > realBaseHours)
    throw new Exception("All hell breaks loose!");

int baseMinutes = (int)(total * 100.0 - baseHours * 100.0);

int finalHours = baseHours + baseMinutes / 60;
int finalMinutes = baseMinutes % 60;

double result = finalHours + finalMinutes / 100.0;
```

Comment: Also, multiply by 100 before subtracting because of [the way floating point arithmetic works](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), otherwise you get 69 for `baseminutes` in this example.

Comment: It's impossible for `baseMinutes` to be >= 100.0 in your code.

Comment: @Askolein My answer works for all inputs, plz check it

Answer (score 0):

It's not good to saving times as a double format, but for your question:

Get all times as array of double values and do some arithmetic:

```
double[] times = { 3.2, 4.5, 5.0 };
int hours = 0;
int minuts = 0;
string[] values;
foreach (double t in times)
{
  values = t.ToString("#.00").Split('.');
  hours += int.Parse(values[0]);
  minuts += int.Parse(values[1]);
}
hours += minuts / 60;
minuts += minuts % 60;
```

It work for all kind of times as double format.

Comment: Seems legit. But why `minuts = minuts*10` ?

Comment: @Askolein for example: 1.5, 1.5> 5+5=10 it have to be 100 ;)

Comment: your parsing method (with `ToString("#.00")`) forces tow digits. Then, it will be "1.50" not "1.5". Your multiplication is not necessary (and wrong actually since "1.51" would give you 510 minutes).